# prestashop 1.7 change lenght product name

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I tried create new product of length 2 charset but it get error "This value is too short. It should have 3 character or more." How can I change min length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change in following file

prestashop17\src\PrestaShopBundle\Form\Admin\Product\ProductInformation.php

line no 150

```
new Assert\Length(array('min' => 3, 'max' => 128))
```